# Audio not working

Tags: sound, 9.04

Anybody could help me in troubleshooting audio problem on Ubuntu 9.04 desktop edition?. For some reason I've to keep this os not upgraded and I'm trying to fix the audio problem on this for months. It works well on upgraded version (9.10, 10.04) but not on jaunty.

aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC883 Analog [ALC883 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC883 Digital [ALC883 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

lsmod | grep snd:

```
snd_hda_intel         436148  7 
snd_pcm_oss            46336  0 
snd_mixer_oss          22656  1 snd_pcm_oss
snd_pcm                83076  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm_oss
snd_seq_dummy          10756  0 
snd_seq_oss            37760  0 
snd_seq_midi           14336  0 
snd_rawmidi            29696  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     15104  2 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                56880  6 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29704  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14988  5 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    62756  21 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_pcm,snd_seq_oss,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              15200  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         16904  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
```

cat /proc/asound/cards:

```
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xe1280000 irq 16
```

cat /proc/asound/version:

```
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.18rc3.
```

vim /etc/modules:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

lp
```

Audio Settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What model of computer is this?

Comment: I didn't get you?. May be you are asking about the motherboard. It's GIGABIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the soundlevel is not set correct.

Please follow the steps:

```
a. Install alsamixergui: Systeem - Beheer - Synaptic packetmanager. 
   Search for: alsamixergui

    Click on alsamixergui and click on the Apply button

b. Start now the alsamixergui and take a look at the sound level
```

If you can't find the alsamixergui, you can start it from the terminal with the command

```
alsamixergui
```

keep me informed

Comment: I've just installed that package and just gave an overview at audio settings and it's fine and I couldn't listen the audio. It may require rebooting the system which I can't do right now as It's in use by the developers. I'll keep you updating...

Comment: I"ve checked, it didn't work.

Comment: I"ve updated my question!

Comment: add following options in your /etc/modprobe.conf.

"options snd-intel-hda index=0 model=3stack"

Comment: It has no `/etc/modprobe.conf` file but I append that line in the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as it as similar lines somewhere in the middle. Still it didn't work...

Comment: As you said `I believe the soundlevel is not set correct.` the problem is with the settings but the hardware settings. The front panel audio ports are not at all connected which I used. I realised this when I could hear audio when connected my earphones to the back panel. Your solution will be helpful if it still doesn't connect even having proper connection. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point might be this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1043568

Comment: Still trying...

Comment: Sorry it was my connection problem!